# view with drop-down howto

Tags: rebol, rebol3

For a `view`, I need to define a size, a `drop-down` with data, set its size and get the chosen value for input in some function.

```
loadGui: func [] [
    unview/all

    view layout [
        Dropd_urls: drop-down (getUrlsEnd Urls)
  ]
]
```

What is a logic behind a `style` or a `facet`? Define a word, than the `facet` then the `size`, `alignment` and other properties, then a block for `on-action`? And what about the `(getUrlsEnd Urls)` that gets evaluated, where should it be placed?  If someone could provide a thorough example on the `drop-down`, it would be great.

And another question. I'm aware of the `help system/...`, but cannot get useful information about the logic of how to accomplish what was stated above.  Where do you go to get to know how to build the `view` constructs? A howto?  Normally, I read the howtos provided by Nick Antonnacio, but there's more to `view` than what is shown in his documents.

Answer (score 2):

the demo on [atronixengineering.com/r3/demo.r](http://atronixengineering.com/r3/demo.r)  has also a dropdown list under widgets. You could generate your dropdown list with compose/deep.

```
view layout compose/deep [
    Dropd_urls: drop-down  [
       (getUrlsEnd Urls) 
    ]
]
```

or with different actions depending of the choice of the dropdown list

```
view layout [
   Dropd_urls: drop-down  [
     "1"
     "2"
  ] on-action [print face/facets/text]
]
```

did you read [Cross Platform App Development with Rebol 3 Saphir](http://learnrebol.com/rebol3_book.html#section-3.5) ?

Comment: The demo only show a `drop-down`, doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: sorry; I did not realize what you meant with getUrlsEnd Urls. I thought you wanted to generate a dynamic dropdown list. In case you want an action depending of your choice I will add a second example